# Have authors ever rewritten their early books to fit future canon in scifi and fantasy works?

Tags: books, canon

In the movie industry there is at least one example (Star Wars) of a franchise where early installments were edited post factum to fit the canon of future releases. However, it is quite hard to edit previously released movies, so you cannot introduce major changes to the plot. But it should be much easier to rewrite a book in order to align it with modern works.

Has there ever been a major book that was re-released to fit into a newer canon? A hypothetical example would be Tolkien rewriting The Hobbit to make it compatible with the Lord of the Rings series.

Comment: [Yes, "hypothetical."](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15493/2865)

Comment: A note for all the people posting answers. A good answer to this question will look like "Yes, here are 2-4 examples". You don't need to list every author who ever retconned, and neither should you add a one off example.

Comment: @amflare: That's fair, maybe a community wiki? I just updated mine.

Comment: Curious, did you already know about the Hobbit rewrite or was it a lucky guess? Just wondering why you referred to it as a hypothetical.

Comment: @jwodder wow, thanks for the link, didn't know that

Comment: @tonysdg, thats one solution to the problem. Though if you do a bit of research and write a good answer on your own, I don't see why you shouldn't get the rep. We don't need an exhaustive answer, just one that supports its assertion

Comment: @Darren it was a guess. I haven't stumbled upon the question about Hobbit editions until now.

Comment: @amflare: Yeah, I haven't got the time to do any further research (I just knew of the Hobbit off the top of my head). So I'll leave it as a community wiki in case others want to add to it!

Comment: To fix [this](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EarlyInstallmentWeirdness) problem, you mean?

Comment: The famous example from fantasy is *The Hobbit* which was rewritten into a prequel to *The Lord of the Rings*. The most notorious example from science fiction is Edward E. Smith's *Triplanetary* which was extensively revised to fit into his *Lensmen* saga. The original story, serialized in *Amazing Stories* in 1934 had no lensmen.

Comment: Per the [FAQ], list questions are off-topic; "*What are all the books that have X?"* = ***"What are all the books that have been edited to include retcons."***

Comment: @Valorum I can't find the word "all" in the question. Question does not ask what are all the books that have been edited to include retcons. It is not a list question, it is a yes/no question. The [consensus](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/are-questions-looking-to-simply-prove-or-disprove-a-premise-with-a-yes-no-answer) seems to be that such questions are on topic.

Comment: @user14111 - Note the run of crap "single example" answers below, the very hallmark of a poorly scoped list question

Comment: @Edlothiad How is your vote to close consistent with what you told me in [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185918/writing-pax-on-the-moon#comment504854_185918)? I guess you are making some distinction which is too subtle for me to figure out without help.

Comment: @user14111 - Because one is very specific, the other is ridiculously broad.

Comment: @Valorum Good questions can attract bad answers. So what?

Comment: @user14111 - Bad questions attract low quality answers (and lotsa them).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Tolkien literally did just that:**

> In the first edition of The Hobbit, Gollum willingly bets his magic ring on the outcome of the riddle-game, and he and Bilbo part amicably. In the second edition edits, to reflect the new concept of the ring and its corrupting abilities, Tolkien made Gollum more aggressive towards Bilbo and distraught at losing the ring. The encounter ends with Gollum's curse, "Thief! Thief, Thief, Baggins! We hates it, we hates it, we hates it forever!" This presages Gollum's portrayal in The Lord of the Rings.
>
> Tolkien sent this revised version of the chapter "Riddles in the Dark" to Unwin as an example of the kinds of changes needed to bring the book into conformity with The Lord of the Rings, but he heard nothing back for years. When he was sent galley proofs of a new edition, Tolkien was surprised to find the sample text had been incorporated. In The Lord of the Rings, the original version of the riddle game is explained as a "lie" made up by Bilbo under the harmful influence of the Ring, whereas the revised version contains the "true" account. The revised text became the second edition, published in 1951 in both the UK and the US.
>
> Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hobbit#Revisions)

**Stephen King also rewrote large sections of the first Dark Tower book:**

> King revised The Gunslinger in 2003. In his introduction to the new edition, King stated that he felt the original version was "dry" and difficult for new readers to access. He also made the storytelling more linear and the book's plot more consistent with the series' ending. Other changes were made in order to resolve continuity errors introduced by later volumes. The added material was over 9000 words (35 pages) in length.
>
> Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Tower:_The_Gunslinger#Revised_and_Expanded_edition)

TV Tropes calls these [Orwellian Retcons](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OrwellianRetcon), and has a number of other examples from literature.

Comment: Also the *Star Wars* novelization, I believe.

Answer (score 8):

Orson Scott Card has frequently rewritten earlier works. For example *Treason* is a rewrite of *A Planet Called Treason*, and he reworked *Hot Sleep* first into *The Worthing Chronicle* and then again into *The Worthing Saga*. Not much of that was for the purpose of fixing continuity errors, but I'd be pretty sure that there were some fixes of that type.

Comment: he updated Ender's Game at least once to better reflect the internet age, if not more, as well

Comment: He talked about this in his most recent blog post. *Early in my career, I began to rewrite some of my first books, until my wife finally pointed out that I really wouldn't have much of a career if I kept rewriting the same five books over and over.* Also, I'll just add here that although he's talked a lot about plans to make major edits to Ender's Game to bring it in line with the later books, he still hasn't ever done so.

Comment: He has modified a few things in Ender's Game, like the name of first colony where Ender is governor.

Answer (score 7):

As a matter of fact, Tolkien *did* rewrite *The Hobbit* to make it compatible with *LotR*.  The rewrites were not large, mainly to the "Riddles in the Dark" chapter.  There's a [good discussion here](http://www.tolkien.cro.net/tolkien/changes.html).

Another approach -- more widely used, I suspect -- is not to change the *words* of the older books, but to later reveal the "secret history" that was really going on so as to change the history without changing the story. This is often done by just showing that the narrator was naive and unaware of the full facts.  Look, for instance, at the recent series of book *X of Worlds* (where *X* is "Fleet", "Juggler", "Destroyer", "Betrayer" and "Fate") by Larry Niven and Edward Lerner.  This is a parallel history to most of Niven's earlier "Known Space"  stories (and includes many of the same characters and places) but it pretty much completely upends what we thought we knew.

Asimov did much the same when he decided that nearly all his novel-length SF was set in the same universe.

Answer (score 7):

As already noted, Tolkien did this, revising *The Hobbit* to make it consistent with *The Lord of the Rings*.

The next most prominent science fiction/fantasy author to do this may be Stephen King, who rewrote  his post-apocalyptic novel *The Gunslinger* to make it fit his later conception of his series *The Dark Tower*.  Per Wikipedia:

> King revised The Gunslinger in 2003. In his introduction to the new edition, King stated that he felt the original version was "dry" and difficult for new readers to access. He also made the storytelling more linear and the book's plot more consistent with the series' ending. Other changes were made in order to resolve continuity errors introduced by later volumes. The added material was over 9000 words (35 pages) in length.
>
> Some changes include:
>
> Roland suffers a dizzy spell at the beginning, a reference to his cyclical quest.

Answer (score 5):

Arthur C. Clarke never rewrote his early stories, but he would "retcon" elements of early books in sequels to bring them in line with advances in scientific knowledge, or events of later books. This is particularly visible in the 2001 / 2010 / 2061 / 3001 series.

And this is probably not what you have in mind, but L. Ron Hubbard rewrote "Dianetics" to bring it in line with later developments in Scientology.

Answer (score 4):

Raymond E. Feist did a preferred edition of [*Magician*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magician_(Feist_novel)) that was mainly to publish it in hardback, but did fix a bit of references and introduced places that were going to be important later.  To quote his discussion from his [website](http://www.crydee.com/raymond-feist/faq/2573/why-was-the-magician-authors-preferred-edition-created):

> I wrote no new scenes, but I did add a couple of references that had been generic in the original that made them specific in the [Author's Preferred Edition]. When Charles tells of the Minwanabi betrayal of the Acoma, I had know [*sic*] in gereral how that was going to fit into a book (if I wrote it) of the other side of the war, but I hadn't named the characters by then. That allowed me to retrofit the references so things would mesh better.